# How to load products which is not in particular category in magento

Tags: magento

I have to load all available products from the particular **attribute-set value** additionally it needs to filter only the products which are not under particular category/categories. How can i load product collection here. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$storeId            = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$catalog            = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setStoreId($storeId);
$collection         = $catalog->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->getSelect()->where(category_id != { cat_id } )->limit($this->products_count);

$_productCollection = $collection;
?>
```

This isn't teste yet and I'm not sure if category_id is the correct value that is used in the database. But it should give you a good start.